# What does "correcting" mean in "even after correcting for gender"? What are exactly are we correcting?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Scholars writing in 2015 found that, **even after correcting** for gender, education, and age, the least cynical people saw an average monthly increase in income of about $300 over nine years.

Link to article: [Live Like the Ancient Cynics](https://www.theatlantic.com/family/archive/2022/01/cynicism-modern-ancient-true-meaning/621314/)

Comment: It's a statistical term. It means leaving aside the issue of gender, education and age.

Answer (score 3):

> [to change an amount, a calculation, etc. in order to make it more accurate, by considering certain facts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/correct)

In this particular example, it means they excluded the issues of gender, education, and age from the study in order to improve the data.

Comment: I agree with Andrew's answer.  The reason you use the word "correct" is because you are afraid that the other factors will bias the data and give you an incorrect idea of what is really going on.  To avoid this, you "correct" for the possibility of bias that could lead to an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: Thanks Andrew , so we are kind of isolating only the cynic part of a person and relating with his/her income changes over the time